# collision angle without physics engine

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, collision-detection

I'm trying to make a collision of bubble to bounce around the left and right screen. I'm using cocos2dx 2.2.5 with visual studio 2012 but I'm still new, so I don't use any physic engine. The ball can stop at the left and right screen, but they don't bounce, just floating until the top of screen.

Here is my code:

```
void level11::move(float delta)
{
   if (getPosition().x > VisibleRect::right().x - radius()) 
   {
       setPosition( ccp( VisibleRect::right().x - radius(), getPosition().y) );
       m_velocity.x *= -1;
   } 
   else if (getPosition().x < VisibleRect::left().x + radius()) 
   {
       setPosition( ccp(VisibleRect::left().x + radius(), getPosition().y) );
       m_velocity.x *= -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your repositioning doesn't work as intended, and the velocity keeps alternating between a positive and negative value. Hard to tell without seeing more code. I'd implement this this way to be safe against this type of problem:

```
if ((m_velocity.x > 0 && getPosition().x > VisibleRect::right().x - radius()) ||
    (m_velocity.x < 0 && getPosition().x < VisibleRect::left().x + radius())) {
  m_velocity.x *= -1;
}
```